# shared_ptr<EVP_PKEY> with EVP_PKEY_free as custom deleter causes heap corruption

Tags: c++, openssl, shared-ptr

Basically, this is what I have:

```
{
    shared_ptr<EVP_PKEY> evpKeyPtr{EVP_PKEY_new(), EVP_PKEY_free};
    //get key from file
}
```

This causes a heap corruption. As well as this:

```
shared_ptr<EVP_PKEY> evpKeyPtr{EVP_PKEY_new(), EVP_PKEY_free};
//same code as above to get key from file
EVP_PKEY_free(evpKeyPtr.get());
//evpKeyPtr does not go out of scope before the corruption occurs
```

But this does not:

```
EVP_PKEY* evpKey = EVP_PKEY_new();
//same code as above to get key from file
EVP_PKEY_free(evpKey);
```

I am at a loss as to why this could be occurring. I know the second code is unadvised, but I did it to test what happens.

Comment: You need to post a full, compilable, runnable test case that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Maybe `std::shared_ptr<EVP_PKEY> evpKeyPtr(EVP_PKEY_new(), [](EVP_PKEY *p){ EVP_PKEY_free(p); });`?

Comment: You might want to try C++11 and `unique_ptr`. I use it frequetly and I know it works. I've never tried the C++03 and `shared_ptr` pattern. For this to work, I believe you need to call `release` (not `get`): `EVP_PKEY_free(evpKeyPtr.release())`. Once you call `release` you cannot use `evpKeyPtr` anymore.

Comment: The middle code isn't what I'm using. I was frustrated as to why the shared_ptr going out of scope would cause a heap corruption but calling EVP_PKEY_free on an unmanaged pointer wouldn't, so I was doing some testing. The heap corruption in the middle code occurs BEFORE the shared_ptr goes out of scope (actually, the heap corruption occurs as soon as I call EVP_PKEY_free on get()).

Comment: I will get a runnable test case up soon.

Comment: can you try the second code like :
`EVP_PKEY* evpKey = EVP_PKEY_new();
//same code as above to get key from file
delete evpKey;`

and let us know result as I am guess here deletion is different than normal c++.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Here is a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Th8MN3Y3) of my problem. The heap corruption occurs at the end of test().

Answer (score 1):

you just get pointer, but shared_ptr keeps to be its owner. it will be deleted twice at the end of scope.

if you want to be able to get the ownership, use unique_ptr (it has release() method).

Comment: The shared_ptr in the middle code is not what my question is about. However, the shared_ptr did not go out of scope before the heap corruption occurred (i.e. the shared_ptr still owned the pointer and calling EVP_PKEY_free on get() caused a heap corruption).

Comment: shared_ptr always releases managed resource in its destructor if pointer to it !=nullptr. but you are trying to delete it manualy in the scope without getting ownership.

Comment: not just trying, you delete it with `EVP_PKEY_free(evpKeyPtr.get())`;.

Comment: You're not understanding what I'm saying. Yes, I do that. I know that if there weren't a heap corruption at `EVP_PKEY_free(evpKeyPtr.get())` that when `evpKeyPtr` would go out of scope that it would attempt to call `EVP_PKEY_free` on the underlying pointer again. I get that. But it's not even getting to the destructor before causing a heap corruption. AS SOON as I call `EVP_PKEY_free(evpKeyPtr.get())`, a heap corruption occurs, so it's not even able to get to the destructor of the `shared_ptr`.

Comment: `int main( )
{
 std::shared_ptr<int> evpKeyPtr{ new int() };
 delete evpKeyPtr.get() ;
 std::cerr << "executed" ;
 return 0 ;
}` try to do something like that and notify about your results.

Comment: I did: `int main() {std::shared_ptr<int> evpKeyPtr{new int()}; delete evpKeyPtr.get(); system("pause"); return 0; }` to make sure the program paused before the `shared_ptr` went out of scope and there was no heap corruption.

Comment: shared_ptrs destructor was not called, as expected.

Comment: but at the point system( pause ) the memory was already freed.

Comment: Yup. But I get a heap corruption if I try `EVP_PKEY_free(evpKeyPtr.get());` before `system("pause");` like I do here with `shared_ptr<int>`. Here is a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Th8MN3Y3) of my problem. What we have been talking about is not in there, however, because I was only using it as a test case to try and help pinpoint the location of the error.

Comment: Hey, thanks for all of the help, but I finally realized what I was doing wrong. It had to do with that `temp` variable at the bottom of `test()`. Thanks for all of your help though! I appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I just realized what I was doing wrong and it has (almost) nothing to do with `std::shared_ptr`. I was attempting to use a temporary that pointed to `std::shared_ptr`'s underlying pointer in an incorrect way.